# Google Data Studio - How to calculate percentage change row by row in a table?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

The users' behavior in my app is registered in a table like the following:

```
| event         |event_count| 
|sign-up button |  10000    | 
|confirm account|  6265     | 
| Log in button |  5248     | 
|ProductX button|  3230     | 
|ProductY button|  1892     | 
|Payment button |  643      |
```

Each event is a button inside the app. The "event_count" column registers the number of clicks on each button.

I want to create a new column that shows the percentage change between the events:

```
| event         |event_count| % change
| sign-up button|  10000    | 0
|confirm account|  6265     | -37,35%
| Log in button |  5248     | -16,23%
|ProductX button|  3230     | -38,45%
|ProductY button|  1892     | -41,42%
|Payment button |  643      | -66%
```

However, I noticed that Data Studio does not have a "row by row" percentage change calculation as a native tool inside the platform. So, I am trying to create a calculated field that would be something like this:

```
round(ifnull(100 * (event_count/lag(event_count) over(order by event_count desc) - 1), 0), 2) || '%'
```

Nonetheless, Data Studio does not have a function called LAG(), which is a function used in BigQuery Standard SQL. LAG () would allow me to select the previous row of the column "event_count". This is important, because it would enable me to calculate the percentage change between the current and the previous row.

Please, do you know how to calculate percentage change by row in Google Data Studio?

Also, I need this table to update according to the date that the user will choose in the dashboard's date range control.

Note: The events that received more clicks will be on top. As the journey is linear, the event in a particular row will usually receive more clicks than the previous one.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart